# Generate CSR with 2 OU Names

Tags: openssl, certificate, keytool, certificate-authority

I have to create an application which generates a CSR. While generating a CSR we are required to fill in several details like CN, OU, etc. The problem is that the Certifying Authority to which I have to send my CSR wants 2 OU(Organizational Unit) Names. I googled a lot but couldn't find anything using either openssl or java keytool by which I can specify 2 OU Names.

Can someone please tell me how I can specify 2 OU Names while generating the CSR?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to do it via CLI you can use either a conf file or pass the -subj argument. Here's an example with -subj

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -subj "/CN=somedomain.com/O=My Corporation/OU=Org Unit 1/OU=Org Unit 2"
```

You can add in ST, L, C, and any other shortName OpenSSL recognizes (along with raw OIDs).

Answer (score 3):

hope this helps I banged my head for several hours till i found it, You can also try this command

```
openssl req -new -key username.key -out username.csr -config client/client.csr.cnf
```

here's the
client.csr.cnf

```
    [req]
    default_bits = 2048
    distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
    prompt = no
    [req_distinguished_name]
    DC= com
    0.DC= company
    OU= organizations
    0.OU= telos
    1.OU= telosapac
    CN= USERNAMEPATTERN
```

notice the number before the subject attribute 0.DC, 0.OU, 1.OU there should be a number prefix representing the index of the subject entries

Answer (score -2):

Openssl allows to set multiple values of the same type by **appending a numeric value** in the openssl confg.

The [openssl manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/x509v3_config.html) states:

> To specify multiple values append a numeric identifier, as shown here:

```
 [extensions]
 subjectAltName = @alt_section

 [alt_section]
 email.1 = steve@example.com
 email.2 = steve@example.org
```

In the case mentioned in the question you would configure

```
[req_distinguished_name]
OU.1 = foo
OU.2 = bar
```

Comment: This actually fails.
You will get this error with this syntax :                              
38804:error:0D06408A:asn1 encoding routines:a2d_ASN1_OBJECT:missing second number:crypto\asn1\a_object.c:78:
38804:error:0B083077:x509 certificate routines:X509_NAME_ENTRY_create_by_txt:invalid field name:crypto\x509\x509name.c:252:name=1
I actually though I remembered it worked like that but it doesn't.
The 0.OU syntax above works.