# Generate CSR with multiple OU using PHP

Tags: php, openssl, certificate, csr

I'm using PHP to create CSR files using the following snippet:

```
$dn = array(
            "countryName"         => 'AU',
            "stateOrProvinceName" => 'State',
            "localityName"        => 'Local',
            "organizationName"    => 'Name',
            "commonName"          => 'org.com',
            "organizationalUnitName" => 'unitName'
        );

$keyAlg = OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA;

$arrayPrivKey = array(
            'private_key_bits' => 2048,
            'private_key_type' => $keyAlg,
            'digest_alg'       => 'SHA256'
        );

$privkey = openssl_pkey_new($arrayPrivKey);

$san = "DNS.1=SAN\n";

$cnf = "[ req ]\ndistinguished_name = req_distinguished_name\nreq_extensions = req_ext\n\n[ req_distinguished_name ]\ncountryName = Country Name (2 letter code)\n\n[ req_ext ]\nsubjectAltName = @alt_names\nkeyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment\n\n[ alt_names ]\n". $san;

file_put_contents('/myPath/openssl.cnf', $cnf);

$csr = openssl_csr_new(
            $dn, $privkey,
            array(
                'digest_alg'     => 'SHA256',
                'req_extensions' => "req_ext",
                'config'         => '/myPath/openssl.cnf'
            )
        );

openssl_csr_export_to_file($csr, '/myPath/test.csr');
```

It works fine, but now I'm trying to create these files with more than one OU (organizationalUnitName), but I'm failing to achieve it.

I've already tried some options like below:

```
//using array
$dn = array(
            //other prop
            "organizationalUnitName" => array('unitName', 'unit2')
        );
//using commas (and other separators)
$dn = array(
            //other prop
            "organizationalUnitName" => "'unitName', 'unit2'"
        );
//using the openssl command line syntax
$dn = array(
            //other prop
            "organizationalUnitName" => 'OU=organizationname/OU=organizationname2'
        );
```

I also tried to use the [extraattribs](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.openssl-csr-new.php) from `openssl_csr_new` function and this is the best option for now, but using it, I'm limited in 4 OUs.

```
//THIS ONE WORKS - LIMITED IN 4 OUS
$dn = array(
            //other prop
            "organizationalUnitName" => 'Unit1',
            "OU" => 'Unit2',
        );
    //code, code,code
$csr = openssl_csr_new(
            $dn, $privkey,
            array(
                'digest_alg'     => 'SHA256',
                'req_extensions' => "req_ext",
                'config'         => '/myPath/openssl.cnf'
            ),
            array(
                 "organizationalUnitName" => 'Unit3',
                  "OU" => 'Unit4',
            )
        );
```

Repeat the key `OU` or `organizationalUnitName` does not work, even with index like `1.organizationalUnitName` ou `organizationalUnitName1` (these last two are not recognized by PHP).

In my previous research, I found this [PHP bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48520) with similar problem, but it refers to a very old PHP version, so it should works fine with the array approach in my environment, but it doesn't.

What I want  as final result is a CSR file similar to the file created with the following command line ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17858752/3943162)):

`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -subj "/CN=somedomain.com/O=My Corporation/OU=Org Unit 1/OU=Org Unit 2/OU=UNIT3/OU=UNITUNIT/OU=MYUNit/OU=FinalUNit" > test.csr`

Are there any way to achieve it using PHP?

The ideal solution should works with PHP 5.6, but I did all tests in PHP7.3 and it fails too. A PHP 7 solution is not perfect for me, but could helps someone with similar problem.

Comment: not supported though with latest version. its easier to make asn1 structure with own function. just like add 060355040B for OBJ_organizationalUnitName. And I also have done on it. make csr with my own function. do you familiar with asn1 structure?

Comment: @Hida, I'm not working on this project anymore, but you can post a solution using the asn1 structure if you want, and I can accept it after the test. If I remember well, I think we solved the problem using a special case for `exec` and used it for the openssl command.