# Generating a certificate with multiple OU fields using pyopenssl

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl

I've been using `pyopenssl` for a while now to generate certificates, specifically the subject line like so:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto

cert = crypto.X509()

cert.get_subject().C = certificate_params.country
cert.get_subject().ST = certificate_params.state
cert.get_subject().L = certificate_params.locality
cert.get_subject().O = certificate_params.organization
cert.get_subject().OU = certificate_params.organizational_unit
cert.get_subject().CN = certificate_params.common_name
```

Now I need to generate a certificate with multiple OU fields, meaning multiple separate OU entries, each with their own value. OpenSSL seems to allow that, and according to [this answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17858752) it can be achieved with the CLI, but I'd like to do that using `pyopenssl`, if it's even possible.

As far as I can tell there isn't a way to achieve this using my original method, as it calls `X509Name.__setattr__`, and that removes any old value instead of adding a new one to the subject line (as evident with the `If there's an old entry for this NID, remove it` comment). There are no other member functions in `X509Name` that allow me to get around that, as far as I can tell.

Is there any elegant method I'm missing, or would I need to use the CLI (or take the hacky route and emulate `pyopenssl` by calling `OpenSSL._util.lib.X509_NAME_add_entry_by_NID` myself)?